# LinqPad and multiple oracle connections

Tags: linq, oracle, linqpad

Is it possible in **LinqPad** to switch the used database connection within one query?
Afaik you can only perform a cross-database join on SqlConnections and not on OracleConnections.

So i would like to perform one request to gather the join data, change the current connection 
and get the needed data via a second select.

Something like:

```
Use Connection1;
var result = from a in b [...]

Use Connection2;
var nextResult = from x in y [...]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible unless the databases have the same schema, in which case you can re-instantiate the TypedDataContext with a new connection string.